# The $k$-skeleton of $n$-cube is homotopy equivalent to wedge of $k$-spheres.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

The fact stated above can be obtained as follows: we just contract faces until all vertices come to one point. The question is how many spheres do we get?

One way to do this is to generalize the method given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1174539

Is there any other not so complicated way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

If a space is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of $m$ $k$-spheres, then
its Euler characteristic is $\chi=1+(-1)^km$, so we can find $m$ by computing $\chi$. In this case the cube structure gives an obvious CW-complex structure so that
$$\chi=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j 2^{n-j}\binom n j.$$

Comment: This is in fact the same argument as in the post linked in the question, just using Euler characteristic as a black box for the outcome of the dimension counting computations with the cellular chain complex.